# p:ajax update of more than one element

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm having trouble when trying to update two elements.

This is my code:

```
<h:form id="all">
        <table id="gt" class="CartContents Stylize General" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:#{clothesBean_i.convertToList(clothesBean_i.cartclothes)}">


            <tbody>


<!--                AFFICHAGE PRODUIT -->
<ui:repeat   value="#{clothesBean_i.convertToList(clothesBean_i.cartclothes)}" var="c">
<tr>
    <td class="CartThumb" style="">
        <a href="http://outdoor-adventures-demo.mybigcommerce.com/foam-rollup-mat/"><img src="" /></a>&#160;
    </td>
    <td class="ProductName" colspan="1">
        <h5><a href=""></a></h5>
        <br />

    </td>

    <td align="center" class="CartItemIndividualPrice">
         $ #{c.price}
    </td>
    <td  id="qt" align="center" class="CartItemIndividualPrice">
    <h:outputLabel for="ajaxSpinner" value="" />
    <p:outputPanel id="mypanel">
        <p:spinner   id="ajaxSpinner" value="#{clothesBean_i.qt}" min="1" max="100">
            <p:ajax update="tot grandT" process="@this" />
        </p:spinner>
    </p:outputPanel>
    </td>

    <td  align="center" class="CartItemIndividualPrice">

    <h:outputText id="tot" value="$ #{clothesBean_i.getClothePriceQt(c)}" />

    </td>

</tr>
</ui:repeat>
            </tbody>
        <tfoot >

                <tr  class="SubTotal GrandTotal">
                    <td colspan="4">Grand Total:</td>
                    <td >
                    <h:outputText id="grandT" value="$ #{clothesBean_i.getClothesPrice(clothesBean_i.convertToList(clothesBean_i.cartclothes))}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tfoot>

        </table>
    </h:form>
```

in this line

```
<p:ajax update="tot grandT" process="@this" />
```

when I give just one id (`tot` or `grandT`) it works fine,
but with two ids I just get a blank page (nothing is showing)!

Comment: put commas between the ids and provide their absolute paths by starting with colons -> <p:ajax update=":all:tot,:all:grandT" process="@this" /> but besides that I think you have mistakes in terms of using the components, particularly the Expression Language and overexhausting business logic at view level. you may want to reconsider your design. – Alp A. 15 mins ago

Comment: You need to use process="@form" instead of using process="@this" to process the elements of the form in the ajax tag.

Comment: Any errors in your server / application log?

Comment: Please edit your question, code is mIssing/not visible.

Comment: I think your problem is becouse the "tot" component is inner ui:repeat, in this case for every repeat will be created an naming container to avoid duplicate ids, but the grandT is out of ui:repeat , so they have diferent prefixes of naming contexts. 
Possible primefaces try to append same prefix to both relative ids.
Please inspect and write your request parameters for this ajax call.

Comment: Actually writing   <p:ajax process="@this"  update="tot , :all:grandT" /> fixed my problem
Thank you all :) and sorry for my code i'm new here

Comment: There is no need to use a comma to separate client IDs. Although you can, it's better to stick with the JSF specification and use a space.

Comment: @JasperdeVries true, I recommended it to improve readability in possible more complex scenarios.